# Using ajax in .each() loop

Tags: jquery, each

I'm trying to use ajax in a loop of tr.

Heres my code :

```
var i=0;
$("tr").each(function() {
var row = datastring;
console.log("I = " + i);
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'somelinkgoeshere.com',
    data: row,
    success: function(){console.log("Success")},
    error: function(){console.log("Error")}
});
i++;
});​
```

### Expected Result

So I want events to be fired in order where console.log must return logs in following **order**:

1. I = 0
2. Success or Error
3. I = 1
4. Success or Error

### Actual Result

But after I run the code the console.log returns logs in following order

1. I = 0
2. I = 1
3. Success or Error
4. Success or Error

***So it means my ajax function is called after my each loop is complete. But I dont want the function to loop unless ajax request is compete.***

Let me know if you need more explanation.

Thanks.

Comment: Ajax is asynchronous, running it in async:false mode will result in a bad UX (the browser will lock until your loop is finished, it will look like your page is broken)

Comment: Ajax is asynch... hey, beat me to it! +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned mutiple times, Ajax is asynchronous. This means that other functions and code can run at the same time, the benefit of this is that the browser doesn't have to wait for a request to finish before continuing with the page JS execution. Imagine what it would be like if you have a dozen Ajax requests on a page and one server takes 30 seconds to respond...

However, if you still want to run the requests synchronously, you can set the `async` flag to `false`:

```
var i = 0;
$("tr").each(function() {
    var row = datastring;
    console.log("I = " + i);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'somelinkgoeshere.com',
        data: row,
        async: false,
        success: function() {
            console.log("Success")
        },
        error: function() {
            console.log("Error")
        }
    });
    i++;
});​
```

P.S. You don't need to manually increment `i`, jQuery's `.each()` can provide it:

```
$("tr").each(function(i) {
    var row = datastring;
    console.log("I = " + i);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'somelinkgoeshere.com',
        data: row,
        async: false,
        success: function() {
            console.log("Success")
        },
        error: function() {
            console.log("Error")
        }
    });
});​
```

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to set `async` to false.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'somelinkgoeshere.com',
    async: false,
    data: row,
    success: function(){console.log("Success")},
    error: function(){console.log("Error")}
});
```

This is not the best thing to do though, as it may lock up the browser, and the whole point of AJAX is to be asynchronous.

Answer (score 1):

Use `async=false`.

Here is a quote from the jQuery documentation:

> asyncBoolean Default: true By default, all requests are sent
>   asynchronously (i.e. this is set to true by default). If you need
>   synchronous requests, set this option to false. Cross-domain requests
>   and dataType: "jsonp" requests do not support synchronous operation.
>   Note that synchronous requests may temporarily lock the browser,
>   disabling any actions while the request is active. As of jQuery 1.8,
>   the use of async: false with jqXHR ($.Deferred) is deprecated; you
>   must use the complete/success/err

or callbacks.